# Proper shebang line for running perl script with an AppleScript on a perlbrew install?

Tags: applescript, perl

I have the following simple AppleScript which calls a perl script I wrote to clean the desktop:

```
do shell script "/Users/stevied/bin/clean_desktop.pl"
```

The script works fine when run from the command line, but when executing the script from my AppleScript, the modules I `use` aren't found and I get this error:

> Can't locate Modern/Perl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
>   Modern::Perl module) (@INC contains:
>   /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18
>   /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.18
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at
>   /Users/stevied/bin/clean_desktop.pl line 3. BEGIN failed--compilation
>   aborted at /Users/stevied/bin/clean_desktop.pl line 3.

I have perlbrew installed. The current shebang line for the perl script is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
```

Comment: I added the following line to the script: use lib `'/Users/stevied/perl5/lib/perl5';` but now get a very weird error: `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _Perl_xs_handshake
  Referenced from: /Users/stevied/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Mac/SystemDirectory/SystemDirectory.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _Perl_xs_handshake
  Referenced from: /Users/stevied/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Mac/SystemDirectory/SystemDirectory.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace`

Comment: Please add additional details, modifications or updates to your question (e.g. as addendum, update or *post-scriptum*) instead of adding comments!

Answer (score 1):

See first comment here for answer: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1191380

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.